# recommendations for material on data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

any good recommendations for databinding.  i am starting to look into WPF more and i want to fully understand the how databinding work under the hood here.  also, WPF is just one example as i assume there is a common pattern with tech like asp.net mvc data binding, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MovingTowardWpfBinding.aspx) is a really nice introductory article on topic.

I can't comment on the semantics of databinding within asp.net mvc; AFAIK in MVC the Controller provides the information but is not aware of the View, and the View takes that information and presents it to the user (and passes user input back to the Controller)

In many ways this is similar to an MVP or MVVM pattern often preferred by WPF developers...

EDIT: Added [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) Binding article

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this is a good description of how to use binding but doesn't explain what is happening under the hood.  i am trying to understand how its working at a low level

Comment: Oh OK... well, the msdn article (I'll edit it to provide the link) goes into more detail to explain Binding Target, Source, Binding type, etc... but I'm not sure if it goes fully "under the hood"...